# How to add body of type NSMutableData to a Request in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, swift3

This is my code extract:

```
let body:NSMutableString = NSMutableString()

body.appendFormat("\(MPboundary)\r\n" as NSString)
body.appendFormat("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\notifications\"\r\n\r\n")
body.appendFormat("\(jsonString)\r\n\n" as NSString)

let end:String = "\(endMPboundary)"

let myRequestData:NSMutableData = NSMutableData()
myRequestData.append(body.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)
myRequestData.append(end.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)

request.httpBody = myRequestData as Data
```

The line:

```
request.httpBody = myRequestData as Data
```

Gives the error "**Cannot convert value of type 'NSMutableData' to type 'Data' in coercion**"

Comment: Your are coding in Swift 3. Why are you using any of those `NS*` classes? Use `String`, not `NSString` or `NSMutableString`. Use `Data`, not `NSData` or `NSMutableData`.

Comment: That is strange: casting `NSMutableData()` to `Data` does compile in my test.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the comments this is a native **Swift** (3) version:

```
var body = ""

body += "\(MPboundary)\r\n"
body += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\notifications\"\r\n\r\n"
body += "\(jsonString)\r\n\n"

let end = "\(endMPboundary)"

var myRequestData = Data()
myRequestData.append(body.data(using: .utf8)!)
myRequestData.append(end.data(using: .utf8)!)

request.httpBody = myRequestData
```

or still simpler:

```
var body = ""

body += "\(MPboundary)\r\n"
body += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\notifications\"\r\n\r\n"
body += "\(jsonString)\r\n\n"
body += "\(endMPboundary)"

request.httpBody = body.data(using:.utf8)!
```

Comment: `var myRequestData = Data()` gives the error "**Missing argument for parameter 'myValue' in call**".

Comment: It looks like you declared somewhere else a custom type `Data`. You should rename it.